# How to use c:foreach to list a list of object inside another class.

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

One of my Object have a list of another object in it. how can i use  to get the list of superperson out. Any Idea or help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
 <table id="contactTable" class="table table-hover" >
     <tr>
         <th width="10%">Date</th>
         <th width="10%">Supers</th>
         <th width="50">Location Seen</th>
         <th width="20%"></th>
         <th width="30%"></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
            Date: <c:out value="${sighting.date}"/>                
        </td>
        <td>
            Super Person: <c:out value="${sighting.superPerson.name}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          Location: <c:out value="${sighting.location.locationName}"/>
        </td>
        </table>


   //class
     public class Sighting {
     private int sightingId;
     private String sighting;
     private String description;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
     private LocalDate date;
     private Location location;
     private List<SuperPerson> superPerson = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jstl forEach tag

here 
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jstl-cforeach-and-cfortokens-core-tags/